# Is it possible to disable the Jitter Buffer in WebRTC (Chrome/Chromium)

Tags: google-chrome, buffer, webrtc, chromium, jitter

I am trying to reduce the Chromium WebRTC video delay as much as possible for a remote machine control application.  Since the transmitting and receiving PCs are directly connected via Ethernet (crossover cable) I'm guessing that receive buffering may not be necessary as there should be no delayed, out-of-order or lost packets.

I have rebuilt Chromium after adjusting the kMaxVideoDelayMs value in jitter_buffer_common.h.  This has given mixed results including creating erratic behavior with receiving video (choppy) as well as making googPlisSent steadily rise over time.  In addition, googJitterBufferMs and googTargetDelayMs jump around erratically when kMaxVideoDelayMs is set lower than a certain threshold (around 60ms).  Everything appears to work well with kMaxVideoDelayMs set to 100ms but I would like to try to reduce overall delay as much as possible.

I would like to know if it is possible to disable or bypass the receive jitter buffer altogether as it seems that might reduce the overall delay between capturing video on the transmitting PC and displaying it on the receiving PC.

Answer (score 1):

You still need a jitter buffer to store the packets until you have an entire frame (and do other related processing that's hung off the jitter buffer).  Audio jitter buffers usually effectively run things, and control when audio/video get displayed.  That's all deep in NetEq, and likely can't be disabled.

If you run audio and video as separate streams (not synced, or no audio), then video should already run pretty much as fast as possible, but if there is delay, it's due to the OS scheduling, and there may also be some amount of pacing delay in the DeliverFrame code (or rather the code that ends up calling DeliverFrame).